# Open an android application with specific fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, hyperlink

I'm thinking how to do it ... but I did not get anything so far.

I would like when the user received a link for example .. when it clicked, my android application would open but with a specific fragment. not on the initial screen of the application ..

This fragment receives an ID as a parameter only.

Is there any way you can do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Deeplinks are used to land a user to a specific screen. By registering deeplinks in your manifest, you can tell Android which **Activity** to open when the user clicks on a link.

For Example:

```
www.foobar.com/         ->  SplashActivity
www.foobar.com/offers   ->  OffersActivity
```

Read more about deeplinks [here](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking)

Once you have navigated the user to the desired activity, your next task is to figure out which fragment to load within that activity. This task you have to do manually within your desired activity.

Override the onNewIntent(Intent intent) of your activity. To get the clicked url by the user, you have to call getData() method on intent:

```
@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
   super.onNewIntent(intent);
   Uri uri = intent.getData(); //http://www.foobar.com/offers/bestoffer
}
```

Once you have this URI, you can use it to figure out which fragment should load.
For example, based on the last path segment:

```
/bestoffer - FragmentA
/secondbestoffer - FragmentB
```